# Is there a way I can check when file was created and last edited in VSCcode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there something similar in VSCode like `ls -l` or `ls -lt` on Linux, or just plain folder table view in Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In windows, if you're using power shell, you can use **ls**, if you're using CMD, you can use the command **dir**.

Now, I don't know if you're trying to make an extension of just list the files in the terminal included in vscode